# Async method block UI Thread Entity Framewok

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

i have please wait form to show the user every time i make a database call. I do not know why but Entity framework is blocking the UI Thread on async methods. This is my code:

```
private async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var formLoading = new FormLoading("Loading data, please wait"));
    formLoading.Show(this);
    var list =  await context.Set<Foo>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    formLoading.Close();
    //....
}
```

when entity framework is making the database call the ui does not refresh and my loading form is frozen. Nevertheless if I make a Task.Delay just before the DB call or put the code in a Task.Run works perfect.

```
private async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var formLoading = new FormLoading("Loading data, please wait"));
    formLoading.Show(this);

    await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var list =  await context.Set<Foo>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    formLoading.Close();
    //....
}
```

this code also works perfect

```
private async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var formLoading = new FormLoading("Loading data, please wait"));
    formLoading.Show(this);
    IList<Foo> list;
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        list =  context.Set<Foo>().ToList(); 
    });

    formLoading.Close();
    //....
}
```

Comment: You are calling the await on that method, which will make it wait for the result of that async method.

Comment: Hi, i move the db call to other method and the same result.

Comment: @ŁukaszTrzewik No, that's not what `await` does.

Comment: Well the thread will be blocked up until the await finishes and .Close() will be called afterwards right?

Comment: @ŁukaszTrzewik No.  It will create a continuation that will execute when the awaited object says it is complete.  The whole point is for it to be asynchronous.

Comment: Remove `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you are on UI thread and you want continue execution in the same synchronization context.

Comment: @Servy sure, but the close method will only be called after async method finishes right?

Comment: @Fabio, i removed .ConfigureAwait(false) and the same result :(.

Comment: @ŁukaszTrzewik Yes, but it won't block the thread in the meantime.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Sorry for saying it wrong way. I meant that it will block the execution of that method.

Comment: Does the version with the `await Task.Delay(1)` still block if you use `ConfigureAwait(true)` on the `Delay()`?

Comment: @sellotape If I use ConfigureAwait(true) the UI blocks, it makes sense because context is the UI Thread and is waiting.

Comment: @RenkoSmith - if you factor `context.Set<Foo>()` out into a previous line (assign it to a new variable), is it still the `await` line that is blocking?

Comment: @sellotape yes, still blocking.